# Excel - Search cell text for exact string fro separate column/array... need exact match

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column of concatenated values that include airport codes within the text.  I have a separate list of 39000 airport codes.  I need to search each concatenated field for any of those airport codes and, if an exact match is found, display it in the field with the formula.

For example, I need to search the text in the left column here for any airport code in my list, which includes KATL. It then returns the values on the right via my formula:

[image]

There will never be more than one match.

The formula is below, which I've used elsewhere.  The problem is that the formula is returning the last partial match... for example, in my airport list I have KATL, KATO, and KATS.  Even though the sentence HAS KATL, the formula is returning KATS (last partial match).

```
=INDEX(reference!$G$2:$G$39170,LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(reference!$G$2:$G$39170,SageReportData1!$P613)),ROW(reference!$G$2:$G$39170)),1))
```

- reference!$G$2:$G$39170 = airport code array/column
- SageReportData1!$P613 = the data cell with KATL I'm searching now

How can I tell this formula to give me the best match with the most characters that don't have spaces?

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, slightly modified version of my formula.

```
=INDEX(reference!$G$2:$G$39170,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(reference!$G$2:$G$39170,SageReportData1!$P13)),-1,1)*(ROW(reference!$G$2:$G$39170)-ROW($G$2)+1)))
```